# Get list of checked checkboxes in table column

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm looking for code which will count and list indexes of checked checkboxes in table column.

For example: in first column I have checked 2 of 3 checkboxes (first and second one), on below column td click I want to get array with checked checkboxes indexes in above column.

Fiddle:

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/1ydryyyq/8/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of data attribute of html.

In HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Val1</th><th>Val2</th><th>Val3</th><th>Val4</th><th>Val5</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker1' checked data-col="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker1' data-col="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker1' data-col="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker1' data-col="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker1' data-col="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker2' checked data-col="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker2' data-col="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker2' data-col="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker2' data-col="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' class='taker2' data-col="5">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' class='taker3' data-col="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' class='taker3' checked data-col="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' class='taker3' data-col="3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' class='taker3' data-col="4">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' class='taker3' data-col="5">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='zero' data-col="1">0.5</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="2">5</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="3">2.1</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="4">0.2</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="5">1.7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='zero' data-col="1">1.4</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="2">0.5</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="3">2</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="4">1.1</td>
      <td class='zero' data-col="5">1.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In script:

```
$("td.zero").on("click", function() {
    var colVal = $(this).attr('data-col');
    var inputSelector = 'input[data-col="' + colVal + '"]:checked';
    var elsInCol = $('#mytable').find(inputSelector);
    var elArray = [];

    $.each(elsInCol, function() {
      elArray.push($(this).hasClass('taker1') ? 1 : $(this).hasClass('taker2') ? 2 : 3);
    });
    console.log(elArray);
});
```

Updated fiddle: [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ydryyyq/11/)

Note: You can also do this using class. I can see you're adding classes row wise (like taker1, taker 2, taker 3). All you have to do is just add classes column wise

Comment: I've edited answer in order to show you selected checkbox items as well